# WPF DataTemplates and Custom Classes to handle events

Tags: wpf, events, datatemplate

If I have a custom class called `VideoMedia` (which contains a standard Uri for the video path) and I have a `DataTemplate` that I use to create a Video Player like controls.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type v:VideoMedia}">
    <MyLib:VideoPlayer/>
</DataTemplate>
```

(*The VideoPlayer class extends UserControl and simply controls the playback of a Video file*)

How do I add an event handler into the `VideoMedia` class, so that it can contain a sort of `TimeStarted` property? I need it at runtime so I can tell if the video is running.

I am storing an `IDictionary<int, VideoMedia>` collection that I iterate over each 2 seconds to tell if the videos are playing. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If your VideoPlayer usercontrol built properly with a IsPlaying dependancy property in it. Just do a Binding to VideoMedia.IsPlaying to the VideoPlayer.IsPlaying and you are good to go.

```
<MyLib:VideoPlayer  IsPlayingDP="{Binding IsPlaying}" ... />
```

Comment: you mean use template binding?

Comment: Just updated the post, IsPlayingDP is your usercontrol property and IsPlaying is your Viewmodel property.

Comment: I'm getting: Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsPlaying; DataItem='VideoMedia' (HashCode=51593576); target element is 'VideoPlayer' (Name='UserControl'); target property is 'IsPlaying' (type 'Boolean')